# Using "random" in a python prog. with "while", "if" and elif"

Tags: python, random, while-loop

Apologies in advance for the Python 101 nature of this question. I have yet to wrap my mind around while loops.

This example is a homework assignment from a book for beginners:

Write a program that randomly opens different fortune cookies and prints each message. The user only needs to hit 'enter' to open one cookie after another.

Here is what I have so far...

```
import random
cookie_number=random.randrange(3)+1
prompt=""
while not prompt:
    prompt=input("Open Cookie")

if cookie_number==1:
    print("your lucky numbers are 3, 22, 107")

elif cookie_number==2:
    print("you are lucky in love today")

elif cookie_number==3:
    print("buy stocks today")

else:
    print("stay away from MSG")
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: If the user hits enter, a zero length string is assigned to `prompt`. Since empty strings are "falsy" the while doesn't break. Assuming this program is supposed to print a single fortune and exit, you should remove the `while` and just do `input("Open Cookie")`. You don't care about the return value, just that the user hit enter to make `input()` return.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that the `cookie_number` is obtained outside the `while` loop, so it will be the same each time the user press enter.

You need to move your second line inside the loop if you want a different `cookie_number` at each iteration.

You can also put an always-true condition in your while loop if you want your user to be able to always open more cookies.

Something like that:

```
import random

while True:
    prompt=input("Open Cookie")
    cookie_number=random.randrange(3)+1

    if cookie_number == 1:
        print("your lucky numbers are 3, 22, 107")

    elif cookie_number == 2:
        print("you are lucky in love today")

    elif cookie_number == 3:
        print("buy stocks today")

    else:
        print("stay away from MSG")
```